# importing state from separate files

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, state

and thanks for reading...

I'm trying to learn redux and right now i have the state declared on separated files.

on store.js i have the state which i want to pass it to one of my reducers, and it's not working nor getting detected on redux dev tools...

heres the code from store.js

```
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import uuid from 'uuid/v4';
import myReducers from './reducers';

const initialState = {
    todos: [
        {
            id: uuid(),
            name: "Go to the gym",
            completed: false
        },
        {
            id: uuid(),
            name: "Pick Milk at the Market",
            completed: false
        }
    ]
};

const store = createStore(
    myReducers,
    initialState,
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
);

export default store;
```

and here's the code from app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import store from './store'
import './App.css';
import TodoList from './components/TodoList';
import TodoInput from './components/TodoInput';

function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <div className="App">
        <h2>React + Redux woth Hooks</h2>
        <TodoList />
        <TodoInput />
      </div>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

finally here's the reducer...

```
import {ADD_TODO, TOGGLE_TODO, DELETE_TODO} from '../actions/types';
import uuid from 'uuid/v4';

const initialState = {
    todos : [
        {
            id: uuid(),
            name : '',
            completed : false
        }
    ]
}

export default function(state = initialState, action){
    switch (action.type) {
        case ADD_TODO: 
            return {
                ...state,
                todos: [...state.todos, action.payload]
            }

        case TOGGLE_TODO : 
        return {
            ...state,
            todos: state.todos.map( todo => (todo.id === action.payload) ? {...todo, completed: !todo.completed} : todo)
        }
        case DELETE_TODO :
            return {
                ...state,
                todos: state.todos.filter(todo => todo.id !== action.payload)
            }
        default : return state;
    }
}
```

Here's the index.js from the reducers folder just in case...

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';
import myReducers from "./postReducers";


const allReducers = combineReducers({
    posts : myReducers
});


export default allReducers;
```

---

Any help would be appreciate at this point

Comment: my todolist doesnt have any code at all, its empty, right now im just trying to see the state stored in store.js and it doesnt have any according to redux dev tools, but i lowkey think its not working properly...

Answer (score 0):

Move `<Provider />` to the root of the project (index.js)

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

In any component that you need to access state, use react-redux's `connect` or `useSelector` (for functional components).

```
// App.js
  export default function App() {
  let posts = useSelector(state => state.posts);

  console.log("++ posts: ", posts);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>React + Redux woth Hooks</h2>
      {/* <TodoList />
        <TodoInput /> */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks but something strange happens now... im able to console.log the state but the logged state is not the one stored in store.js but one initialized on the reducers(and im trying to pass the state from the store because i was told is over there that the initialized state must be declared...), but the weird thing is the state doesnt show up on the redux dev tools...

Comment: preloadedState object you pass to the createStore(). Which means initial state passed in createStore will show instead of initialState passed in reducers. For your case, initialstate passed to createStore() can be accessed as state.todos. Read more https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/initializing-state